# Bitcoin core read-only

Tags: bitcoin-core, bip32-hd-wallets

I have system where users can generate addresses and bring some coins, and get bonuses after. I want to make my core read-only. For this I have a second bitcoin core which have not connected to internet. So as I read I can change the MPK of my general core for the MPK of offline core. That is why the online core will be read-only.

Help me please to solve this problem!

Comment: You can add addresses to your "read-only" node as watch only addresses

Comment: How can I do that? Is this associated with extended mpk ?